# Remove words from string except within quotes

Tags: python, regex, string, nltk, stop-words

I'd like to remove the stopwords from a string, apart from quotes within the string.

For example, if the stopwords were:

```
stopwords = ['this', 'is', 'to', 'the']
```

I'd like the string:

```
orig_string = 'This is an example, "I want to keep this text" but still remove the stopwords'
```

To become:

```
new_string = 'an example, "I want to keep this text" but still remove stopwords'
```

As you can see, the stopwords have not been removed from the quote within the string, but have been removed from the rest of it.

I am currently using this:

```
new_string = ' '.join([word for word in orig_string.split() if word not in stopwords])
```

to remove the stopwords but am unsure how this can be adapted to suit my needs.

I think the solution might involve using a regular expression lookaround like this `r'(?<=")([^"]+)(?=")'` but that would involve me removing the quote from the string and I'm not sure how I would place it back in the original string position.

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

This is how I ended up implementing it:

```
split_string = orig_string.split('"')

temp_strings = []

for i in range(len(split_string)):
    if i % 2:
        temp_strings.append(split_string[i].lower())
    else:
        temp_strings.append(' '.join([word for word in split_string[i].lower().split() if word not in stopwords]))

new_string = ' '.join(temp_strings)
```

Comment: Capture the substrings between quotes, and just match the stopwords, use the callable as the replacement argument to analyze the match data object to replace accordingly.

Comment: you can split `orig_string` by `single quote`, then iterate over it and apply your filtering on **even** indexes only.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your reply but I don't quite understand what you mean by that. Would you mind providing an example?

Comment: @HadiRj Thanks for the suggestion, my implementation is probably not the most efficient but that works great :)

Comment: [This is what I meant](https://ideone.com/xhfBh4).